# Not able to use conda python version in VSCode outside of workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, version, conda, miniconda

I have problems to use the base conda python version when executing a python command outside of a script in a workspace in VSCode. This is despite the fact that I am specifying the python.pythonPath in the User Setting. The problem only happens in VSCode

First of all I am on a Mac with OS Big Sur (Version 11.6). I have miniconda installed in the following location:
/Users/username/opt/miniconda3

In .zshrc there is the conda initialization script

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/matthiaslenfers/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/matthiaslenfers/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/matthiaslenfers/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/matthiaslenfers/opt/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

When opening the terminal per default I am in the conda base environment.

```
(base) username@Matthiass-MBP ~ % which python
/Users/username/opt/miniconda3/bin/python
```

As you see outside of VScode in the terminal I don't have any problems using the conda base python version.

Inside of VSCode I opened a workspace and changed the settings to a specific conda
python version (and I also changed the general user setting)

```
User Setting
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/matthiaslenfers/opt/miniconda3/bin/python"

Workspace Setting
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/matthiaslenfers/opt/miniconda3/envs/example_project/bin/python"
```

When executing a line (import pandas as pd) from the file example.py in the workspace example_project (by highlighting it and then pressing ⇧ + Enter) I get the following result:

```
source activate example_project
/Users/username/opt/miniconda3/envs/example_project/bin/python
import pandas as pd
(base) username@Matthiass-MBP example_project % source activate example_project
(example_project) username@Matthiass-MBP example_project % /Users/username/opt/miniconda3/envs/example_project/bin/python
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 07:03:16)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
```

So the correct python version of my conda environment example_project is used automatically

When on the other hand I open a new terminal inside VSCode and check the python version and location I get the following result and the active python version is /usr/local/bin/python

```
(base) username@Matthiass-MBP example_project % which python
python --version
Python 2.7.15

(base) username@Matthiass-MBP example_project % which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Why is it not the Python version in /Users/username/opt/miniconda3/bin? It shows
(base) in the VSCode terminal, but another python version is executed

I am confused!

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of the python interpreter you have selected. You can get it from the bottom-left on the VSCode.

[image]

After you selected the python interpreter, **when you create a new terminal in the VSCode(shortcut of Ctrl+Shift+`), the python extension will help you to activate the environment automatically** like this:

[image]

You can have a look at the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment). It explained it clearly.